# Does removing an app from the recent apps list in Android cause it to disable any alarms that have been set by the alarm manager in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am currently developing an Android app using Android Studio. One of my requirements is to trigger the `BroadcastReceiver` at an exact time. It is working perfectly fine until the app is running in the background. Once the app is killed from the recent apps list, it doesn't work. I don't know whether the problem is in the alarm manager or in the `BroadcastReceiver`.

XML:

```
<receiver android:name=".BackgroundServer"
    android:permission="TODO"
    tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="birthday.wallpaper.WALLPAPER_CHANGE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in MainActivity (Java):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,BackgroundServer.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
        .getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0,intent,0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
assert manager != null;
manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        pendingIntent
);
```

In my custom Broadcast Receiver, I have set the alarm manager in the `onStart` method of `MainActivity`. This means, like alarms, the `BroadcastReceiver`'s code must be executed.

Well, it works when the app is in the foreground or when the app is closed but present in the recent apps list. The code is not executed when I try to remove the app from the recent apps list. I don't know whether the alarm is disabled when I remove the app from the recent apps list, or perhaps the Broadcast Receiver stops listening to Broadcasts.

Comment: set it in ondestroy

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin That won't do anything.  If the alarm is being cleared, it will be cleared no matter when you start it

Comment: What version and device?  Some devices make swipe away in recents perform a force stop, which will kill all pending alarms.  In fact it kills everything for the app until the user manually launches it again.

Comment: set your alarm manager with sticky service

Comment: Greg has answered your query about urgency in the comments. The main question is now on hold, mainly for the inclusion of the phrase "doesn't work". What does this mean? If you can explain what is not working (what should have happened? What did not happen? What errors did you get?) then perhaps it can be reopened.

Comment: @halfer I have written a certain code inside my custom Broadcast Receiver. I have set the alarm manager in the onStart method of MainActivity. This means, like alarms, the BroadcastReceiver's code must be executed.Well, it works when the app is in the foreground or when the app is closed but present in the recent apps list. The code is not executed when I try to remove the app from the recent apps list. I don't know whether the alarm is disabled when I remove the app from the recent apps list. Or the Broadcast Receiver stops listening to Broadcasts...        Hope you understand my problem now.

Comment: Please, always, add improvements to posts by way of an edit, rather than just in the comments. On this occasion I have taken your text, lightly edited it for clarity, and tried to summarise what I think your actual problem is in the title. **Please would you confirm that the question is now an accurate statement of your problem**, and if not, edit it. It may then be okay to reopen.

Comment: Well, not alarms in general... but the alarm manager in the android apps. I have updated the question and please reopen the question.

Answer (score 0):

You used a dynamic declared receiver. This means that it is created and registered in your activity. You declare this type of receivers and register in onResume().When you kill your activity you have to unregister it in onStop(). If you don't unregister, you are going to get an error called LeakIntentMemory, however activity unregister it by itself and app don't crashes.

But when you look at logcat you are going to see the LeakIntentMemory error. And this type of receivers works as you tell.When you close app you can not receive anything. If you want to receive something whenever your app closed, you have to declare your receiver in android manifest. For more examples check my GitHub https://github.com/okanSerdaroglu/BroadcastReceivers

Comment: I have also included it in the android manifest... But the problem is not yet solved. Does unregistering the receiver will make it stop listening to broadcasts??

Comment: Maybe. Did you try to remove it from onStop ?

Comment: I have also tried to remove it from onStop... Still, it doesn't work...

Comment: Serdaroglu Do you know any other alternatives of alarm manager